# GraphQL relationship in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, graphql

I have the following GraphQL Schema

```
type User {
  id: String!
  name: String
  username: String!
}

type Conversation {
  id: String!
  participants: [User]
}

type Query {
  user(_id: String!): User
  conversation(_id: String!): Conversation
}
```

My resolver for the conversation is as follows:

```
conversation: async (parent, args) => {
  let conversation = await Conversation.findById(args._id);
  conversation.id = conversation._id.toString();
  return conversation;
}
```

The `participants` field will hold array of users ObjectId. What do I need to do in my resolver so I can fetch users data within the `conversation` call.

For example a call like this

```
query test($id:String!){
  conversation(_id:$id){
    id,
    participants {
      id,
      username
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably used Reference in your object model, therefore in order to fetch participants data, you should use [mongoose populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)!

This would work for you:

```
conversation: async (parent, args) => {
  let conversation = await Conversation.findById(args._id).populate('participants');
  conversation.id = conversation._id.toString();
  return conversation;
}
```